# cre loaded 6.4.1 admin

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed cre Loaded 6.4.1 on localhost and live server

on localhost i get error in admin panel

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): 
  The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: 
  use mysqli or PDO instead 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\osc\admin\includes\functions\database.php on line 19
```

I also installed cre loaded on live server but admin panel is not working (admin panel is opening)
facing error on admin page.

```
404 Page Not Found
Sorry! The page you requested is unavailable. 
Please use your browser's Back button, or go to the home page.
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* PHP functions which are now deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future. So you need to use MySQLi or PDO instead, just as the error notice warned you.

PDO

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname) VAULES('John', 'Doe')");

MySQLi

$db = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO table(firstname, lastname) VAULES('John', 'Doe')");